# How can I return just a single class instance from a SQLite query?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I've got this SQLite code to try to retrieve a record:

```
String qry = String.Format("SELECT ChallengeTypeFK, {0}, {1} FROM LettersWordPhrases WHERE Id = ?", keyLang, candidateAnswersLang);
List<DBModels.LettersWordsPhrases> lwp = dbConn.Query<DBModels.LettersWordsPhrases>(qry, randomId);
```

I would prefer to just assign the results of the query to a single DBModels.LettersWordsPhrases, but it says that's not possible, that it needs a List<> . Why would that be necessary, when I only want to return one record?

How can I get it to just return one record, rather than have to extract the first (and only) element from the result set?

Comment: could you add more informations like, what type is that dbConn?

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it seems to be Dapper, but then I am wondering if that code compiles.

Comment: @Steve Dapper returns `IEnumerable<T>`, so `lpw` assignment would be invalid.

Comment: Try `DBModels.LettersWordsPhrases pw = dbConn.ExecuteScalar<DBModels.LettersWordsPhrases>(qry, randomId)`.

Comment: I'm not using any ORM; this is a quick-and-dirty utility. I've never heard of dapper, nor would I probably be described in that way (I hope not, anyway). This is dbconn:
static readonly SQLiteConnection dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("multilingual.sqlite");

Comment: I tried ExecuteScalar first and it didn't work; now it is (working). And I didn't even see any ladders or walk under any black cats today. I'm not superstitious - I'm not even a little bit stitious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
String qry = String.Format("SELECT ChallengeTypeFK, {0}, {1} FROM LettersWordPhrases WHERE Id = ?", keyLang, candidateAnswersLang); 
DBModels.LettersWordsPhrases lwp = dbConn.Query<DBModels.LettersWordsPhrases>(qry, randomId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Remember to check if lwp is null, in case no record was returned.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), you can also use `FindWithQuery` to do what you are looking for:

```
String qry = String.Format("SELECT ChallengeTypeFK, {0}, {1} FROM LettersWordPhrases WHERE Id = ?", keyLang, candidateAnswersLang); 
DBModels.LettersWordsPhrases lwp = dbConn.FindWithQuery<DBModels.LettersWordsPhrases>(qry, randomId);
```

Comment: I think that your post should be marked as answer, as it's more suitable for this purposes